# Overlays: Color subformulas successively

Tags: beamer, overlays

I want to color different subformulas with overlays successively.

```
\frame{

   \onslide<1>{$$\textcolor{red}{a} \land (\textcolor{red}{b} \lor c)$$} 
   \onslide<2>{$$\textcolor{red}{a} \land (b \lor \textcolor{c})$$} 
}
```

Unfortunately the formula "jumps" down one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's supposed to be something like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\def\ca#1{\temporal<1>{#1}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}{#1}}
\def\cb#1{\temporal<2>{#1}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}{#1}}

\frame{

   $$\textcolor{red}{a} \land (\ca{b} \lor \cb{c})$$ 
}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong with simply

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\frame{
$$\textcolor{red}{a} \land (\textcolor<1>{red}{b} \lor \textcolor<2>{red}{c})$$ 
}
\end{document}
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\alt` overlay specification:

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \alt<2>{\[\textcolor{red}{a} \land (b \lor \textcolor{red}{c})\]} 
    {\[\textcolor{red}{a} \land (\textcolor{red}{b} \lor c)\]}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You specify the `alt`ernate slide (containing the first mandatory argument), while the remaining slides will contain the second mandatory argument.